# FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL with ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On top of exposing all temporal tables as traditional tables, to enable auditing I'm exposing all temporal tables separately with the `FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL` hint. This is easier to consume as the current record is also found in the resultset then.

However, an `ORDER BY` on my Account table in conjunction with the temporal `FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL` hint is causing it to spill data into tempdb. This is a real performance killer. I need the `ORDER BY` for pagination. I've also tried a `UNION` of both the temporal table and the history table and applying an `ORDER BY` on that but this naturally leads to the same performance problem. Can anything be done to adress this problem?

Below you will find the actual execution plans. Indexes spanning across the primary key and the period columns are present on both tables as can be seen.

Just `FOR SYTEM_TIME ALL`:

[image]

Just `ORDER BY`:

[image]

`FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL` with `ORDER BY`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the problem is not spilling data to disc. It's an effect, not the root cause. In the first query there is no order by, so SQL Server could give you any row. In the second query there was an index on Account that supported the sort. In the last query the data was spilled, because on history table there is no index on `ID`, so SQL Server had to read all the history records to be able to give you a record sorted by `ID`. I think that craeting a nonclustered index on the history table on `ID` might help (you cannot create a clustered index on History, becuase there is already on Account).